# Automatic differentiation in policy gradient networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I do understand the backpropagation in policy gradient networks, but am not sure how works with libraries that auto-differentiate.

That is, how they transform it into a supervised learning problem.
For example, the code below:

```
Y = self.probs + self.learning_rate * np.squeeze(np.vstack([gradients]))
```

Why is Y not 1-hot vector for the action taken?
He is computing the gradient assuming the action is correct, Y is one-hot vector. Then he multiplies it by the reward in the corresponding time-step. But while training he feeds it as the correction.
I think he should multiply the rewards by one-hot vector instead.
https://github.com/keon/policy-gradient/blob/master/pg.py#L67

Answer (score 0):

Y is not a 1-hot vector because it is the sum of action probability (ie `self.prob`) multiplied by its corresponding reward.